# How to play binary MP3 stream with jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mp3

I'm getting a pure binary MP3 stream from an ajax call. No headers, nothing.  Just straight MP3 bits. (Actually is that really even a stream at all?)

I'd like to be able to play it in a web page (and, if possible, offer it for downloading).

Is this possible?  And if so what's the best way to do it?

If it is not possible, what are some other ways to handle this?

Comment: Should have mentioned that I know I need a flash player or something like it.  I was most interested in how to play a stream of this type without a URL or a file...

Comment: so the ajax response contains a string which holds the entire mp3 file? or does the response give you a url of that stream?

Comment: The former.  A string with just the binary mp3 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant play music with pure javascript. you will need to get that stream and pass it to a flash player.

try [JW flash player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/), though i am not sure if it can handle the type of stream you are talking about. you will have to do some research about what it can handle

Comment: surely flash isn't the only option?

Comment: it's the most cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

as indeed mentioned, you'll need a mp3 playing plugin, flash being the most widely available.
The [JMP3](http://www.sean-o.com/jquery/jmp3/) jquery plugin makes that task easier for you. It does rely on a flash file for the sound processing.

Comment: Ya, I'm trying that one now.  But I don't see how to pass it the data.  In a var?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only targeting [very modern browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support), you could make use of data URL:s, and just write an object element to your HTML, and link to that data URL. Note: I havn't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [SoundManager 2: Javascript Sound for the Web](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

Its an open-source BSD licensed JavaScript script for dealing with sound.

It automatically hooks into HTML5 or Flash to produce the sound, depending on what is available.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using [data uris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and there is the browser compatibility issue, there is the problem of url length (basically > about 30,000 characters won't support IE) and there is also the problem of the browser taking forever to decode the base64 value (the buffering is also extermely slow).

With current web technology, I would say your best bet is to write the data to a temporary file on your server and then have something like [Dewplayer](http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer-en) load the temporary file and play it.